# How do I bring up an interface on a netscreen router

Tags: networking, router, netscreen, screenos

I took down an interface using

```
set interface ethernet0/0 phy link-down
```

with the intention of cycling it back up - but now I can;'t figure out how to bring it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
unset interface ethernet0/0 phy link-down
```

Comment: So obvious... many thaks!